# No transpila archivo a usar babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Intentando aprender las nuevas cosas que aporta ES6, estoy siguiendo pasos para transpilar mi primer archivo, pero no lo logro conseguir; no me aparece ningún error, no aparece nada malo al intentar hacer la operación.

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de la pagina, y sigue de la misma manera

`npm install -g babel-cli`

`npm install --save-dev babel-cli`

Lo único que hace es crear un archivo idéntico al que quiero transpilar, pero con el nombre de salida que le desee colocar.

`babel --watch archivo_es6.js --out-file archivo_es5.js`

#### Codigo

```
let saludo;

saludo = `hola
mundo`;

console.log(saludo);
```

Comment: Con ese comando instalas la línea de comandos de babel, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta para aclarar __cómo__ estás _traspilando_ tu archivo?

Comment: @toledano listo, ya agregue dicha linea

Comment: Coloca un __[mcve]__ que permita reproducir el comportamiento que reportas. Dado que estás usando correctamente `babel`, solo queda suponer que es tu script el origen. Tal vez no estés usando ninguna función relacionada con ES6.

Comment: @toledano listo, agregue el código de ejemplo el cual estoy siguiendo

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que la apóstrofe se acepta de la misma manera que una comilla simple y/o doble?

Comment: No puedo reproducir el comportamiento señalado, yo si observo la conversión. Verifica si tienes configuraciones relacionadas con `babel` que estén alterando la salida, puede ser un archivo llamado `.babelrc` o `.babel.rc`. También es posible que exista un apartado relacionado en `packages.json`. Con los elementos que aportas no existe ningún problema. Los archivos de babel pueden ser globales o locales. Pero el problema no se puede reproducir.

Comment: @fredyfx es parte del standard de ES6 - [Plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Comment: gracias hermano @Mariano, necesito un F5 en el tema :D

Comment: mr @fredyfx no sabia esto, quier decir que tendre beuna suerte XD

Answer (score 1):

El codigo es correcto solo tendras que agregar `use strict` al principio del archivo para poder usar la pa

Babel tiene la capacidad de transpilar diferentes verciones de ES pero tu tines que definir a que version quieres hacerlo atravez de los presets para transpilar de es6 a es5 primero tienes que instalar el preset de es2015
    `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

Despues crea un archivo .babelrc aqui puedes poner todas las configuracion y preset que ocupes.

```
    {
       "presets": ["es2015"]
    }
```

Y ejecuta de nuevo el comando `babel --watch archivo_es6.js --out-file archivo_es5.js` y el resultado es el siguiente.

Comment: lo probare gracias

Comment: em aparece el siguiente error, `C:\Users\PterPmntaM\cursoES6\aprendiendoes6\node_modules\regenerator-transform' -> 'C:\Users\PterPmntaM\cursoES6\aprendiendoes6\node_modules\.regenerator-transform.DELETE`, pero es debido que dicha carpeta y posibles archivos dentro de esta no existen

Comment: Ya intentaste  corriendo `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 ``?

Comment: Precisamente, ese error me sale al correr ese comando